# How to create italic "in press"-year labels for in-text citations by modifying the bibtex style file

Tags: bibtex, formatting, natbib, italic

I'm looking for a way to add "in press" in italics into my bibtex-style file for publications for which a doi already exists.
As I'm using a Natbib-AuthorYear reference style, I have to add this in two areas, for the bibliography and in-text citations. The first part (bibliography) worked out already. The following code produces an italic label "in press"-label in the list of references (bibliography):

```
FUNCTION {format.date}
{year duplicate$ empty$
    { 
     doi empty$
      {pop$ "????" }
      {pop$ "in press" emphasize }
     if$ 
    }
    'skip$ 
    if$
 ". " swap$ * * "" *
}
```

However, The second part (in-text citations) causes some problems.
I figured out that I have to add this to the function calc.label:

```
FUNCTION {calc.label}
{ 
  calc.short.authors
  short.list
  "("
  *
  year duplicate$ empty$
  short.list key field.or.null = or
     {
      doi empty$
       {pop$ "????" }
       {pop$ "in press"}
     if$ 
      }
     'skip$
  if$
   * 
  'label :=
}
```

However, adding "emphasize" behind "in press" as in the former function, causes an error. I wrote another small function which produces me an italic "in press" label for the in-text citations, but I have problems to add this to the calc.label function:

```
FUNCTION {in.press}
{ "in press"
  emphasize
  "" * }
```

Basically, replacing:

```
{pop$ "in press"}
```

with

```
{pop$ "a" in.press *}
```

in the calc.label-function creates the italic "in press" but can not stand alone. so I have to put an nonitalic letter infront (here "a") of it:

Author1 et al. (a *in press*)

(without the space between "a" and "in press")

Does anyone know how to deal with this???

Thx a lot!!!